# React's invalid prop type 'array' expected 'object'

Tags: reactjs

I'm displaying company info in detail page (coming from list of companies, sending ID in params through React Link)

Now we're talking about the detail page. I receive the ID, call the api for json array:

```
 {"_id":"58f7f61cff8d4014d7f7730b","company_name":"Vodafone" .... }
```

and expect it as:

```
export default class Detail extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    getCompany: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    **company**: PropTypes.array,
  }
```

Everything works, is received and displayed, but I still get the warning saying:

```
"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `company` of type `object` supplied to `Detail`, expected `array`."
```

I'm still quite new to react, so I suppose maybe my API isn't returning an array, but when I switch the prop definition of company to "object" I get the same warning with reversed problem - receiving array, expecting object, so that's a circle I can't find the way out of.

Has anyone seen anything similar before? Is the problem with company prop or the API?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty self explanatory: the value you are passing is a single object containing company data. So the correct prop type would be `PropTypes.object`, like this:

```
export default class Detail extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        getCompany: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        company: PropTypes.object
    }
}
```

If your data is sometimes an array, sometimes an object, you can use this:

```
export default class Detail extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        getCompany: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        company: PropTypes.oneOf([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array])
    }
}
```

But this would kind of defeat the purpose of the whole prop types thing, so you should perhaps make sure you always pass an array *or* an object to the component.

Comment: I thought the same, but if you read the last paragraph of my post you can see I already tried changing that and the warning appears in switched order - expecting object, getting array and that's the weirdest part about it.

Comment: @foxy That means you are probably sending sometimes an object and sometimes an array. You could work around that using `PropTypes.oneOf([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array])` but probably there is some mistake in you logic because you should not be using one property with different types.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan, I added your input to my answer (hope that's OK with you )

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for the tip! Even though I realise it's not the best solution, it works. And when talking about sending different type (object/array) - this warning shows up on the detail page of the same company after reload. The data are the same, code is the same, the only thing I change is the proptype and it always asks for the different one.

Comment: Excellent tip @Sulthan -- this made me realize there was a bug in initialState.